# How to share a hotspot wifi access (like fon) accross my ethernet network?

Tags: wifi, router, nat, wifi-hotspot

I'm moving into a new home and won't be able to have an actual "wired" xdsl 
 (or better) internet access for several weeks.

Fortunately, there are a few hotspots that require http authentication (like fon) around, and i have access to those (basically my cellphone provider is also an isp and thus i have a valid login/password)

I'd like to share that internet accross my ethernet network.

I have a box with a wlan and eth interface, and i want to log on the hotspot (manually type log/pass once a day) and have 3 computers on the network have access to the internet through that connection.

So basicaly I think I need a dhcp server which does not sound very hard to do, and something to act as a router/nat...

I've used debian a little bit but i don't know much about networking with linux...

Any help is appreciated !

Thanks !

Comment: Can you please tell me what kind of Wireless Router did you use?

Comment: @angelo306 I didn't have any, I was using a linux computer and a wlan usb stick

Answer (score 2):

You can use this script [linux-router](https://github.com/garywill/linux-router)

Connect Internet hotspot on your box and run this on box:

```
# lnxrouter -i eth0
```

(assume `eth0` is connected with 3 computers)

That script will do ther nat and dnsmasq(DHCP and DNS) jobs.

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple to do if you have a wireless router handy. :)  Connect to the hotspot with your wireless adapter.  Then go to the configuration of the onboard adapter and under the IP v4 Settings tab, change "Automatic DHCP" to "Shared To Other Computers".  I usually set IP v6 to "Local Link Only".  Now plug the ethernet cord into the WAN port of your wireless router and you have wireless across the house.  This is my current setup, and works great.

-Jay

Comment: I'm going to try that thanks... I don't want wireless across the house though, i want 3 computers that are connected using ethernet cables to be able to use the same hotspot at the same time... So i guess i just plug the cable into a switch and set a dhcp server up ?

Comment: exactly.  use the hub/switch's uplink port.  its usually the last port. the internet sharing will provide dhcp for your switch.  note! i ran into an issue with xubuntu 16.04 and with a kubuntu, (can't remember the version)... the dhcp didn't install masquerade and the sharing did not work @ all!  i made this quick script to run after i install a box showing this problem:

Comment: i don't know why i couldn't put this link in that post, but whatever. here is the script to make ICS work if it don't by default.  https://goo.gl/WMLTFj